# Proposal for a Writing SE custom logo

Tags: discussion, design

I like this site and I really want to design it. Lately, I'm trying to make custom logos for Stack Exchange sites that doesn't seem to have one.

Just like [Arduino's logo](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/), I thought of a simple logo put up on the iconic Stack Exchange default logo speech bubble.

[image: Writing SE]

Just a pen/marker on the bubble. It's not exactly as good as my 2 previous proposals which are [Ethereum](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/663/a-suggestion-for-the-sites-logo) & [Windows Phone](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395/proposing-a-logo-for-windows-phone-se), but its just a proposed one, so nothing really special.

What ways do you want to make the Writing SE logo? If possible, when are we having a Writing SE logo at all (apart from the current one)?

Comment: A relevant post (on this meta) by one of our Community Managers from last week: [Custom Writing design and logo - Information gathering](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2492/24064) :)

Comment: Update: [Your new site design is live!](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2566/24064) – and the final logo is pretty close to what you suggested, aside from it being a pencil instead of a pen/marker :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for your proposal. I'm glad you enjoy your time here.

> If possible, when are we having a Writing SE logo at all (apart from the current one)?

Unfortunately, we don't know. As of the time of writing, it's been over 1 1/2 years since we graduated, and we have heard nothing about getting a custom site design. None of the [other sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331708/461068) that graduated at the same time as us have received custom designs, either.

I expect that when we finally do get a custom design, it'll be everything at once: banner, colours, and perhaps a custom background like Worldbuilding.SE has, as well as a new logo. Those elements will all be decided at that time, and you'll be welcome to make your logo proposal if and when that time comes. For now, though, there's not really much we can do with this proposal.

Comment: Do we edit the question to say status-declined or status-deferred now?

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot that you're meant to do that. Thanks for reminding me.